# Position fixed 100 of parent

Tags: css, fixed

I'm in difficulty: I have a parent element that has a size that doesn't know. And I have an item that it must place permanently at the top of the body, then `position: fixed`, but I cann't because giving it `width: 100%`, is 100% of the body, but I want 100% of the parent element. How can I do?

Example: http://codepen.io/michele96/pen/jWbYQb

Answer (score 14, accepted):

set `.fixed`'s width as `width: inherit;`  don't use `100%`

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 70%;
 height: 1000px;
 background: red;
}

.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 width: inherit; /*change here*/
 line-height: 50px;
 background: blue;
 color: #f0f0f0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="fixed">Navbar Fixed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea in this case. But note it wouldn't work if `.container` were inside a `.super-container` with a `width` different than `100%`.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that, unlike absolutely positioned elements, the containing block of a fixedly positioned element is usually the viewport, not its nearest positioned element. Then, `width: 100%` is resolved with respect to the viewport width.

There are ways to change this behavior, e.g. elements with `transform` establish a containing block for their fixedly positioned descendants. But then your element won't be fixed at the top of the viewport.

Instead, you should use sticky positioning:

```css
.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed">Navbar Fixed</div>
</div>
```

Note it's not widely supported yet.

Comment: @AmrNoman Bad?? .. that was nicely put :) .. but looking forward when we can use it cross browser

Answer (score 1):

Set `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to the parent.

Comment: Just a bit of friendly advice, a full code block would severely improve the quality of your answer. i.e. `.container { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }` (obviously formatted properly) and an explanation of why you say that it works would be bonus points :)